# How to Get Aggregate Data by Time Slice (sum, avg, min, max, etc.) in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

How can I create active relation queries in Rails 3 that are aggregated by time slice?

I'd like to build queries that for every n minute interval can return min, max, avg, sum, count, for every sample of a counter with a particular name.

```
create_table "samples"  
    t.integer  "counter_id"  
    t.string "name"  
    t.float    "value"  
    t.datetime "created_at"  
end
```

Comment: Time slices referred to created_at of `Sample`? And `counter has_many :samples`? And you need to find max, min etc of `value`?

Comment: Hi fl00r, Yes exactly. And by time slices I mean I would like to aggregate all sample values within each interval (eg: 1 or 10 second intervals) into a single resulting value for each interval, but at the same time retrieve many intervals without a separate query for each of the intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I've never used Postgres, so this solution works in MySQL. But I think you can find out Postgres analogs.

```
class Counter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :samples do
    # default 30 minutes
    def per_time_slice(slice = 30)
      start = "2000-01-01 00:00:00"
      self.select("*, 
                   CONCAT( FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'#{start}',created_at)/#{slice})*#{slice},  
                     (FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'#{start}',created_at)/#{slice})+1)*#{slice} ) as slice,
                   avg(value) as avg_value, 
                   min(value) as min_value, 
                   max(value) as max_value, 
                   sum(value) as sum_value, 
                   count(value) as count_value").
                   group("slice").order("slice")
    end
  end
end
```

Usage

```
counter = find_some_counter
samples = counter.samples.per_time_slice(60).where(:name => "Bobby")
samples.map(&:avg_value)
samples.map(&:min_value)
samples.map(&:max_value)
```

etc

Comment: Change CONCAT(bla, bla) into bla || bla to make it more PgSQL likeable.

Comment: Apologies flOOr, this was a great answer, and I only realized today that I hadn't hit the accept checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Samples.where("SQL for the time slice goes here").where(:name, "Views").average(:value)
```

You can also swap average for any of minimum, maximum and sum.

Comment: With what you propose, if I was retrieving 1000 small time slices,  would there then be 1000 queries?

Comment: I added a bounty as I think I need to get into the weird DB magic, as 1000 queries per request will be too costly. Upvoted for giving me some of the rails 3 answer... Thank-you