# Aggregate Event cost by month when Event ranges more than one month (in rails 3)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, date

I have this `Event` model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :starts_at, :ends_at, :price
end
```

An `Event` can be a single instant event:

```
Event.create(:starts_at => Date.today, :ends_at=>nil, :price => 10.0)
```

It can also span multiple days or months:

```
Event.create(:starts_at => Date.today, :ends_at => (Date.today + 2.months), :price => 20.0)
```

I want to break down the cost of events by months, so that cost for an instant event falls into the month it belongs to, naturally, and cost for an event that spans multiple months should be divided proportionally between those months.

Obviously this would be difficult to handle using SQL, but maybe someone has some advice on that?

What would be the most efficient way of calculating this aggregation?

**Update:**

Here is a clearly defined structure for the data on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a532e/6

What I would want from this dataset is something like:

```
( (Date('2013-01-01'), 31.6), (Date('2013-02-01'), 8.4) )
```

Comment: It would be *very helpful* if you provided a clearly defined table with with dummy data. Maybe even an [sqlfiddle[http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197806/how-to-get-aggregate-data-by-time-slice-sum-avg-min-max-etc-in-rails-3?rq=1 may help you

Comment: "difficult to handle using SQL". Challenge accepted. :). Also, I suggest you add an primary key to your test case and edit the question to put the link in there.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've updated my question per your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT event_id
      ,date_trunc('month', day)::date AS month
      ,sum(daily) AS price_this_month
FROM  (
   SELECT event_id
         ,generate_series(starts_at
                         ,COALESCE(ends_at, starts_at)
                         ,interval '1 day') AS day
         ,price / COALESCE((ends_at - starts_at) + 1, 1) AS daily
   FROM   events
   ) a
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a532e/7)

I provided an updated sqlfiddle for PostgreSQL. Your original seems to be for MySQL.

#### The tricks are:

- Use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to create one row per day for every event.
- Use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to take care of `NULL` values, which seem to be allowed for `ends_at`.
- Calculate the `daily` cost by dividing the price by the number of days between `starts_at` and `ends_at`
  `+ 1` to fix off-by-one.
  Default to 1 in case of `ends_at IS NULL`.
- Re-aggregate per event and month.

Voilá.

You even get *exact* rates per month, depending on how many days a month has. February (28 days) is cheaper than January (31 days).

Comment: Bravo, i was trying to figure it out but you are the first and its elegant!

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Thanks. I added some improvements

Comment: sqlfiddle seems to have troubles atm. My query doesn't seem to get saved.

Comment: That looks pretty awesome! I'll try it in my actual environment tomorrow but it works in sqlfiddle so I'll mark this as correct now.